# How to update UI on async callbacks in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

(I'm new to Android development, so this might be a basic question. I've searched the best I can.)

I'm relying on a service that updates data asynchronously and provides a callback when there is new data. I'm trying to figure out how to use this to update my UI whenever the data changes.

I've gone through the basic Jetpack Compose tutorials and I can build a UI with a button that updates a count. Based on that knowledge, the best idea I came up with is to create a `MutableState` in the ComponentActivity's `init` method. This is working, but I don't know if it's the right way to do this.

Here's my code (obfuscated a bit to remove private details):

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    // Get the updating value from the async service
    private val asyncService = getAsyncService()
    private val updatingValue = asyncService.getUpdatingValue()

    // Create a MutableState for the UI
    private val mutableValue = mutableStateOf(updatingValue.value)

    init {
        // Update the MutableState whenever the value changes
        updatingValue.onUpdate { newValue ->
            run {
                mutableValue.value = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            ExampleComponent(mutableValue)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ExampleComponent(value: MutableState<String>) {
    Text("The value is : ${value.value}")
}
```

Is this right or is there a better way to do this?

Update:

I wrote a ViewModel class like this and it works great:

```
class AsyncDataViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val asyncService = getAsyncService()

    private val updatingValue = asyncService.getUpdatingValue()
    val value = mutableStateOf(updatingValue.value)

    init {
        updatingValue.onUpdate { updatedValue ->
            run {
                value.value = updatedValue.value
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jetpack Compose, you should use a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to manage the data that is displayed, as explained in [this lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#0). A ViewModel

- retains the data even if configuration changes (e.g. rotation) occurs
- provides easy access to a CoroutineScope to execute suspension functions asynchronously
- allows to expose state to a Composable.

I provided a sample architecture below:

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val asyncService: AsyncService  // using Koin dependency injection
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _mutableValue = mutableStateOf("")  // for write operations
    val mutableValue: String = _mutableValue // for read operations

    init {
        this.loadValue()
    }

    fun loadValue() {
         viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
             // You have a CoroutineScope here. You can execute async suspension functions here.
             // call suspension function in AsnycService class
             _mutableValue = asyncService.getUpdatingValue()  
         }
    }
}
```

Then, you can get your ViewModel in your Composable like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
   amyViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
) {
   Text("The value is : ${myViewModel.mutableValue}")
}
```

Your service class should use a [suspension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html) function. Your ViewModel will call this function as a Coroutine without blocking the UI thread and will update the value and refresh the value automatically:

```
class AsyncService {
    suspend fun getUpdatingValue(): String {
        delay(5000)  // some long running operation
        return "HELLO"  // value that is returned after operation  
    }
}
```

This way, you also get rid of specifying callback functions.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. My `updatingValue` updates multiple times in the background automatically. I should be able to use the `updatingValue.onUpdate` callback in this ViewModel, right?

Comment: I updated the original question with an example of my ViewModel. This is working great. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know where your `AsyncService` is getting its data from. But if that data source properly uses Kotlin and `suspend` functions, it would not be necessary to have a callback with the new value. Instead, your `getUpdatingValue` function would simply return the new value itself, and the ViewModel will asnychronously wait for the return value and then will automatically update the UI as soon as the updated value is written to the `mutableValue` variable. This is the benefit of Kotlin `suspend` functions and Coroutines, you get rid of the callbacks you would need with Java.

Comment: Got it. AsyncService is something something we've built in-house, hence why I'm obfuscating it's actual name. It needs to be used in both Java and Kotlin so I think it might need the callback method to support Java. Not entirely sure about that. But it can also update multiple times at any point in the future and we want the latest value all the time.